# How do I center two <h> tags as one element while having them stacked on top of each other?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have 2 h tags. I want them both to be centered as one element while being stacked on each other. Using flex box keeps them in the same line, how do I do it?

Comment: please put your code and explain more what you want

Comment: do you want them to be stacked on top of each other or do you want them in the same line?

Comment: @MrXQ Stacked..